# AWS Chime SDK - Javascript - ChimeSDK is not defined

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-chime-sdk, amazon-chime

I am trying to find (download/create) Chime SDK javascript file to include in my html page for creating meetings.

However, i cannot find a direct download anywhere.
So, by following instruction on this page 
(*Bundling Chime SDK into a single .js file*): 
https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-chime-sdk/tree/main/utils/singlejs

as follows:

```
git clone https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-chime-sdk.git
cd amazon-chime-sdk/utils/singlejs
npm install
npm run bundle
```

I generated the javascript file (amazon-chime-sdk.min.js), and included it in my HTML page as follows:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="assets/js/amazon-chime-sdk.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    Welcome!
    <script>
        //Error on next line: ChimeSDK is not defined!
        const logger = new ChimeSDK.ConsoleLogger(
            "ChimeMeetingLogs",
            ChimeSDK.LogLevel.INFO
        );
        const deviceController = new ChimeSDK.DefaultDeviceController(logger);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

However, i get this error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: ChimeSDK is not defined
```

What am I doing wrong here, is the javascript file not generated correctly?
Alternatively, where can I find Chime sdk client javascript to include in my html page?

Comment: Did you check the browser console for any errors? It seems that the aws-chime-sdk-client script was not loaded properly.

Comment: Yes.. this error is from browser console: "Uncaught ReferenceError: ChimeSDK is not defined"

Comment: Can you put your code to JSFiddle or Codesandbox?

Comment: It seems ChimeSDK Global variable was not properly set from the SDK bundle. No issues on your code.

Comment: JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/r5Loz3m4/   So, any idea why javascript file is not generated on expected lines - as described in instructions? Or where can one download aws chime sdk client javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output bundled code was not having `ChimeSDK` global variable. Update the `src/index.js` file with the following code and then rebuild the code with `npm run bundle`.

```
export * as default from 'amazon-chime-sdk-js';
```